# Java subobject/submethod

Tags: java

I would need help because I don't know how to make a submethod when I want something().nic(), for example. So I would need advice on how to do such a thing. My Code is below. And I would need to do `team.getPlayers().playing()`. This method should return a list of players who can still play.

My code:

```
package net.malejmarabu.gs.games.files;

import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class Team {
    public enum TeamColor {
        RED,
        BLUE,
        GREEN,
        PINK,
        YELLOW,
        WHITE,
        GRAY,
        AQUA
    }

    public class TeamData {
        public static Team getTeamByColor(Game game, TeamColor color) {
            return teamsByColor.get(game).get(color);
        }

        public static Team getTeamByPlayer(Player player) {
            return teamByPlayer.get(player);
        }

        public final static TeamColor[] t_colors = {TeamColor.WHITE, TeamColor.AQUA, TeamColor.YELLOW, TeamColor.GREEN, TeamColor.BLUE, TeamColor.RED, TeamColor.GRAY, TeamColor.PINK};
    }

    private static final HashMap<Game, HashMap<TeamColor, Team>> teamsByColor = new HashMap<>();
    private static final HashMap<Player, Team> teamByPlayer = new HashMap<>();;

    private final TeamColor color;
    private int status = 0;
    private final List<Player> players;
    private final Game game;

    public Team(TeamColor colour, Game game, @Nullable List<Player> players) {
        this.color = colour;
        this.players = players;
        this.game = game;
        status = 2;

        teamsByColor.put(game, new HashMap<TeamColor, Team>());
        teamsByColor.get(game).put(colour, this);

        for (Player player : players) {
            if (teamByPlayer.containsKey(player)) {
                teamByPlayer.remove(player);
            }

            teamByPlayer.put(player, this);
        }
    }

    public TeamColor getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public void addPlayer(Player player) {
        players.add(player);
        teamByPlayer.put(player, this);
    }

    public void removePlayer(Player player) {
        players.remove(player);
        teamByPlayer.remove(player);
    }

    public List<Player> getPlayers() {
      return players;
    }
}
```

I tried to use AI and I also searched on google, but I couldn't find anything.I don't know how to proceed, please help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the Players class has a variable for whether the player can play, and the equivalent getter method. You can do the following using the Stream API:

```
team.getPlayers().stream().filter(player -> player.canPlay()).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

You cannot call `playing()` on `getPlayers()` because it returns a `List<Player>`. So you can only call methods that apply for lists.

I would suggest to create a function on the Team class, that returns the players that can still play:

```
public List<Player> getPlayersThatCanPlay() {
    return players.stream().filter(player -> player.canPlay()).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: As a note, you can refine the _stream_ invocations, `getPlayers().stream().filter(Player::canPlay).toList()`.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I would need help because I don't know how to make a submethod when I want something().nic(), for example. ... This method should return a list of players who can still play. ..."*

You could *encapsulate* an *ArrayList*, and add a *playing* method.

```java
private final PlayersList<?> players;
static class PlayersList<T extends Player> extends ArrayList<Player> {
    Player[] playing() {
        return (Player[]) stream().filter(Player::isPlaying).toArray();
    }
}
```

And, as a recommendation, use a *static import* for the *TeamColor* enum.

```java
import static Team.TeamColor.*;
```

```java
t_colors = { WHITE, AQUA, YELLOW, GREEN, BLUE, RED, GRAY, PINK};
```

Also,